# java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean Shared Preference (RadioButtons)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, radio-button, sharedpreferences

In the app there is two radiobuttons and each buttons has its own value that is first radiobutton has value of "2" and second radiobutton has the value of "4". Now i successfully implemented the shared preference in order to save the value by clicking the radiobutton. But there is one thing is missing which is if i select radiobutton 1 and if i close the app and again open the app then the radiobutton 1 is not selected. I also tried to add the `radiobutton.setChecked` but it get crash. Below is the xml and java code.

> custom_dialog.xml

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="15dp">
    <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup" />
</ScrollView>
```

> method0.xml

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="method0">
        <item>2</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

> method1.xml

```
<resources>
    <integer-array name="method1">
        <item>4</item>
    </integer-array>
</resources>
```

> CustomDialog.java

```
public class CustomDialog extends AppCompatDialogFragment {
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater=getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        final View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dialog,null);
        RadioGroup radioGroup=view.findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
        final int[] num0=getResources().getIntArray(R.array.method0);
        final int[] num1=getResources().getIntArray(R.array.method1);
        RadioButton radioButton0=new RadioButton(getActivity());
        RadioButton radioButton1=new RadioButton(getActivity());
        radioButton0.setText("A");
        radioButton0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int method=num0[0];
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("METHOD",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", method);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
        radioButton0.setPadding(0,50,0,50);
        radioButton0.setTextSize(17);
        radioButton0.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        radioButton0.setChecked(Update("key")); //Here this line it is getting crashed
        radioButton1.setText("B");
        radioButton1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int method=num1[0];
                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("METHOD",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
                editor.putInt("key", method);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
        radioButton1.setPadding(0,50,0,50);
        radioButton1.setTextSize(17);
        radioButton1.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton0);
        radioGroup.addView(radioButton1);
        builder.setView(view)
                .setTitle("Select Any Methods")
                .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });
        return builder.create();
    }
    private boolean Update(String key){ 
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getActivity().getSharedPreferences("METHOD",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(key,false); //Here this line it is getting crashed
    }
}
```

> MainActivity.java

```
    btnMethod.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openDialog(); //this will open the dialog along with two radiobuttons
        }
    });
private void openDialog() {
    CustomDialog customDialog=new CustomDialog();
    customDialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"Custom Dialog");
}
```

> Logcat

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nabil.myapplication, PID: 17062
    java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getBoolean(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:326)
        at com.nabil.myapplication.CustomDialog.Update(CustomDialog.java:295)
        at com.nabil.myapplication.CustomDialog.onCreateDialog(CustomDialog.java:69)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not much aware of the android codes, However, if I just go through your error, then it is coming because there is no parent-child relationship between the two classes Integer and boolean.

Comment: Yes i am storing the key in the shared preference which is in `int` and when i call this function `radiobutton.setChecked` which is in `boolean` it gets crashed.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are storing an integer in the shared preferences and then trying to retrieve a Boolean.

I suggest storing the value of the radio button like so:

```
editor.putBoolean("radioButton0", radioButton0.isChecked());

...

editor.putBoolean("radioButton1", radioButton1.isChecked());
```

**EDITED:**

Instead of using

```
editor.putInt("key", method);
```

Use:

```
editor.putBoolean("radioButton0", radioButton0.isChecked());
```

**AND**

Instead of using

```
radioButton0.setChecked(Update("key"));
```

Use:

```
radioButton0.setChecked(Update("radioButton0"));
```

This should work like you want it to.

Comment: I am using `editor.putInt` to store the value and also pass to the api which i successfully pass this store `int` value to the api. But when it comes to `radiobutton.setChecked` if close the app and reopen that selected radiobutton is unchecked and also crash.

Comment: @SOUGATRIYADH Either you store value as boolean and retrieve as boolean or store as Int and retrieve as Int. You should not save as int and retrieve as boolean.

Comment: @iamanbansal It is fine, i can retrieve the int value but for example i select first radiobutton and it store the `int` value in `shared preference` now i decided to close the app and once again i open the app that first radiobutton is still unselected which i selected before closing the app.

Comment: Check the edited answer, maybe its more clear what I am trying to say